# How to download big size images using <a> tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to connect to the database and view pictures from there. Despite the fact that all pictures are shown, it is not possible to download them. To download I use tag .

Here is my code.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                    {  
                         echo '  
                              <tr>  
                                   <td align="center"> 
                                        <a href="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Pilt'] ).'" download>
                                            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['Pilt'] ).'" width=400 class="img-thumnail" />
                                        </a>
                                   </td>  
                              </tr>  
                         ';  
                    }
```

Here is a small part of the database where I get pictures. https://i.stack.imgur.com/cERJb.jpg . So I noticed that only one photo is being downloaded, which size is 150.4KiB.

I expect that by clicking on the image (any size) it will be downloaded. Right now when I click on image appears error like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZC5K.jpg whereas I would like to see something like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX2cv.jpg .
I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you stop printing large quantities of big images that way, they will be hardcoded in the HTML code and downloaded all at once to the browser's cache, 2 times (3 with the click included). This wastes RAM and bandwidth. The network error you get is probably caused by the abnormally big size of the `href` in your link (might even look a bit like malware to your browser).

Instead, you want to serve these images dynamically on a PHP script first (by setting the header to `'Content-Type: image/png'` and printing the image contents as obtained from your database) and provide a direct URL to the script.

This example works just as described in your screenshots, I'm indicating where you should replace your SQL queries to obtain the image:

```
while(for all your rows)  
{  
echo '  
  <tr>  
    <td align="center"> 
      <a href="image.php?id=' . $id . '" download>
        <img src="image.php?link=' . $id . '" width=400 class="img-thumnail" />
      </a>
  </td>  
</tr>';
}
```

And `image.php` would look something similar to:

```
<?php
$id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);
header('Content-Type: image/png');
$content = store the image contents from the BD here ($row['Pilt'] in your code);
echo $content;
```

Notice that `image.php` serves images dynamically and I'm supposedly identifying each image with an id (perhaps your row id? You can think of more secure identifiers too if ids are not public already). This is a common security practice in PHP so that you're not providing absolute file paths or other information to attackers.

Comment: Just a minor nit... use `htmlspecialchars()` around that `$id` in PHP so that you don't accidentally open yourself up to XSS attacks, should that ID end up coming from user input.

Comment: I meant, where you're actually outputting HTML.  It should be no problem at all in your image script, as it will never be echoed.  The only time you need `htmlspecialchars()` is when you're putting data in the context of HTML.  Even if you can assume things about the `$id` (such as it always being numeric), you never know when at some point in the future, this page gets generated from user input.  (`/users?id="/><script src="something-evil.js"></script>`)  That's how these bugs get introduced later, so *always* escape the data when putting it in the new context.

Comment: ah, right, probably very implementation dependant, if an attack already made it to the DB that's a problem in itself